# Dynamically added forms JQuery array to PHP (CodeIgniter) and back (with errors)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, validation, dynamicform

I have a form that has its fields dynamically added as such:

```
function addFieldRow() {
  $('.form-container').append('
    <div><input type="text" name="name[1]"></div>
    <div>
      <select name="choice[1]">
        <option value="red">red</option>
        // . . .
      </select>
    </div>
     // . . .
  ');
}
```

I then pass these to its respective CodeIgniter controller with the declared array form_validation rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]', 'text field', 'required');
// . . . other fields' rules
```

The problem is that if any of the dynamically added forms have an error, these are gone during the view loading. 
I want to know if **how can I preserve the dynamically added form fields after the validation run with errors**:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  // do stuff to preserve the dynamically created fields to show their errors
  $this->load->view('user_addresses_view');
}
```

### Better solution

I have found the solution to preserve these dynamically added elements by using `ajax` to connect to the form's respective controller in the CodeIgniter framework. This method can:

1. Do client-side and server-side validation without refreshing the page
2. Since the page does not refresh, all these dynamically added form elements will not disappear!

Solution by [james246](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797551/dynamically-duplicated-forms-disappear-on-codeigniter-reload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do it because page is actually refreshing and row is added **client side** so when validation done then you will redirected to same page with **validation errors** you will not see dynamically added dom because as i said **it was happend client side not in your code**...so all you can do is use `session` and then at load time manually validate and add them to page.

Using `SESSION` might not be good idea because for that you will have to code more complex helpers and validation methods and etc...

**Other possible solution**

1. use `jQuery.validate` plugin that allow us to validate dynamically added rows ( fields , dom ).
2. take benefit of mysql and add those field into database with possible error stored in db and send it to view file.

Comment: Sir, thank you for the explanation and suggesting the alternatives!
I'll try jQUery.validate now!

Answer (score 0):

In view :

```
 for($i=0; $i<$ttl_input;$i++)
    {
    <div><input type="text" name="name[".$i."]"></div>
    <?php echo form_error('name['.$i.']'); ?>
    }
```

in controller:

```
foreach($this->input->post('name') as $index=>$name)
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name['.$index.']', 'text field', 'required');
}
```